# rsnapshot taking a long time to backup, are the scripts correct?

Tags: rsnapshot

I am wondering if the backup system I am maintaining was incorrectly setup from the start which may explain why it is slow.

**Backup Objective:**
Carry out daily incremental backups from a NAS storage (Terastation Buffalo NAS) to a Ubuntu computer over a 1gb switch using rsnapshot.

**Problem:**
Daily RSnapshopt takes 9hours to diff about 160GB of data, this feels like a long time but I do not know what to expect.

**Details:**
rsnapshot is called by cron daily.

The rsnapshot.conf file appears to be the default template:

```
#######################
# CONFIG FILE VERSION #
#######################

config_version  1.2

###########################
# SNAPSHOT ROOT DIRECTORY #
###########################

# All snapshots will be stored under this root directory.
#
snapshot_root   /srv/backups/

# If no_create_root is enabled, rsnapshot will not automatically create the
# snapshot_root directory. This is particularly useful if you are backing
# up to removable media, such as a FireWire or USB drive.
#
no_create_root  1

#################################
# EXTERNAL PROGRAM DEPENDENCIES #
#################################

# LINUX USERS:   Be sure to uncomment "cmd_cp". This gives you extra features.
# EVERYONE ELSE: Leave "cmd_cp" commented out for compatibility.
#
# See the README file or the man page for more details.
#
cmd_cp      /bin/cp

# uncomment this to use the rm program instead of the built-in perl routine.
#
cmd_rm      /bin/rm

# rsync must be enabled for anything to work. This is the only command that
# must be enabled.
#
cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync

# Comment this out to disable syslog support.
#
cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger

# Uncomment this to specify the path to "du" for disk usage checks.
# If you have an older version of "du", you may also want to check the
# "du_args" parameter below.
#
#cmd_du     /usr/bin/du

# Uncomment this to specify the path to rsnapshot-diff.
#
cmd_rsnapshot_diff  /usr/bin/rsnapshot-diff


#########################################
#           BACKUP INTERVALS            #
# Must be unique and in ascending order #
# i.e. hourly, daily, weekly, etc.      #
#########################################

interval    daily   7
interval    weekly  4
interval    monthly 3

############################################
#              GLOBAL OPTIONS              #
# All are optional, with sensible defaults #
############################################

# Verbose level, 1 through 5.
# 1     Quiet           Print fatal errors only
# 2     Default         Print errors and warnings only
# 3     Verbose         Show equivalent shell commands being executed
# 4     Extra Verbose   Show extra verbose information
# 5     Debug mode      Everything
#
verbose     2

# Same as "verbose" above, but controls the amount of data sent to the
# logfile, if one is being used. The default is 3.
#
loglevel    3

# If you enable this, data will be written to the file you specify. The
# amount of data written is controlled by the "loglevel" parameter.
#
logfile /var/log/rsnapshot

# If enabled, rsnapshot will write a lockfile to prevent two instances
# from running simultaneously (and messing up the snapshot_root).
# If you enable this, make sure the lockfile directory is not world
# writable. Otherwise anyone can prevent the program from running.
#
lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

# Default rsync args. All rsync commands have at least these options set.
#
#rsync_short_args   -a
#rsync_long_args    --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded


# Default arguments for the "du" program (for disk space reporting).
# The GNU version of "du" is preferred. See the man page for more details.
# If your version of "du" doesn't support the -h flag, try -k flag instead.
#
#du_args    -csh


# The include_file and exclude_file parameters, if enabled, simply get
# passed directly to rsync. Please look up the --include-from and
# --exclude-from options in the rsync man page for more details.
#
#include_file   /path/to/include/file
#exclude_file   /path/to/exclude/file

# If your version of rsync supports --link-dest, consider enable this.
# This is the best way to support special files (FIFOs, etc) cross-platform.
# The default is 0 (off).
#
#link_dest  0

# When sync_first is enabled, it changes the default behaviour of rsnapshot.
# Normally, when rsnapshot is called with its lowest interval
# (i.e.: "rsnapshot hourly"), it will sync files AND rotate the lowest
# intervals. With sync_first enabled, "rsnapshot sync" handles the file sync,
# and all interval calls simply rotate files. See the man page for more
# details. The default is 0 (off).
#
#sync_first 0

# If enabled, rsnapshot will move the oldest directory for each interval
# to [interval_name].delete, then it will remove the lockfile and delete
# that directory just before it exits. The default is 0 (off).
#
#use_lazy_deletes   0

###############################
### BACKUP POINTS / SCRIPTS ###
###############################

# LOCALHOST
backup_script   /usr/local/bin/backup_smb_share_All.sh  All/
```

All the backup_script "backup_smb_share_All.sh" essentially contain:

```
smbclient <hostname>/<share> -U<username>%<password> -Tc - 2>/dev/null | tar xf -
```

NOTE: I am aware of the bad practise of hard coding the username & password in the script.

My understanding of this script is a bit fuzzy but it mainly seems to login and configure the "Tar" settings. It appears to copy data but I don't see how that is configured in the above line.

Looking at the logs (/var/logs/rsnapshot) the following happens:

```
[05/Jan/2015:02:43:47] mkdir -m 0755 -p /srv/backups/tmp/
[05/Jan/2015:02:43:47] cd /srv/backups/tmp/
[05/Jan/2015:02:43:47] /usr/local/bin/backup_smb_share_All.sh
[05/Jan/2015:04:44:15] cd /root/
[05/Jan/2015:04:44:15] sync_if_different("/srv/backups/tmp/", "/srv/backups/daily.0/All/")
[05/Jan/2015:13:43:25] /bin/rm -rf /srv/backups/tmp/
```

1. Is the backup script sensible?
2. By the looks of it the bottleneck is "sync_if_different", so that would be a Ubuntu server performance limitation?
3. Is this all as expected for such a system?

Comment: Isn't there a way to just make it use timestamps? Have you tried `rsync` for this purpose instead?

Comment: Umm... your subject line said you are using rsnapshot, but the snippet of script you posted shows nothing of the sort.  That `smbclient` command just downloads everything from that server share using `tar` as a transport.  You really should show the whole script.

Comment: So you are syncing over samba instead of syncing over rsync? If so, rsync will always copy whole files instead of only deltas.

Comment: I believe it is copying using samba because the terastation is only offering that as protocol? I may be wrong.